# If $g''(x)>0$ prove that if $E(g(X)) = g(E(X))$ then $X$ is a constant random variable.

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, expected-value

I know that when $g''(x)>0$ it means that $g$ is strictly convex. By Taylor's theorem we have:

$$
g(x) = g(E(x)) + [x - E(x)]g'(E(x)) + \frac{[x-E(x)]^2}{2}g''(\epsilon_x)
$$
for $\epsilon_x\in(x,E(x))$. So for $g''(x)>0$ we have
$$
g(x) > g(E(x)) + [x - E(x)]g'(E(x))
$$

But I have no idea how to prove that if $E(g(x))=g(E(x))$ then $X$ is a constant random variable. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013864/equality-in-jensens-inequality-for-strictly-convex-functions

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Define the linear functional $l(x) = g(EX) + g'(EX)(x-EX)$, and note that $g(x) > l(x)$ for $x \neq EX$.

Now consider $E[g(X)-l(X)]$ and show that if $X \ne EX$ on a set of positive measure, then $E[g(X)-l(X)] >0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't get the second part

Comment: What is $E[l(X)]$? Remember that expectation is linear.