# Proof that $KL(p||q) =0 \iff p(x) = q(x)$

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, machine-learning

I am studying Machine Learning, and I came across a proof in section 1.61 in Bishop's textbook *Pattern Recognition & Machine Learning* which I couldn't quite understand. The claim is that $KL(p||q) = 0$ iff $p(x) = q(x)$, where $KL$ denotes the *KL Divergence*.  The key idea is the strict convexity of $-\lg x$. I covered the proof of Jensen's inequality a while ago and I understand it, but I don't understand the last equivalence, equation 1.118 on page 56:

\begin{equation}
KL(p||q) = - \int p(x) \ln \left\{ \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} \right\} dx
         \geq -\ln \int q(x) dx = 0
\end{equation}
Bishop follows this inequality with "where we have used the fact that $−\ln x$ is a convex function, together with the normalization condition $\int q(x) dx = 1$. In fact, $−\ln x$ is a strictly convex function, so the equality will hold if, and only if, $q(x) = p(x)$ for all $x$."

Why is that? I get that the fact that the function is strict means that
on the interval $[a,b]$, for any $a < x < b$, $f(x) < c(x)$, where $c(x)$ denotes the point on the chord from $a$ to $b$ at $x$, and $f(x) = c(x)$ only at the points $x=a$ and $x=b$. It's probably very obvious, but I don't see the equivalence.... I
get that the integral of the PDF $q(x)$ integrates to 1 and thus the
right-hand side of inequality 1.118 is consequently zero. And I certainly
understand that if $q(x) = p(x)$, then you have equality. But why does
equality imply that $q(x) = p(x)$?

For additional context, note that the claim is found in the section on *Relative Entropy and Mutual Information*, where it is used to show that the *mutual information* between variables $x$ and $y$ is zero if and only if the KL Divergence is zero, that is if $KL(p(x,y)||p(x)p(y)) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [condition for Jensen's inequality to be an equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628386/when-jensens-inequality-is-equality) is that the concave function is affine or the random variable is a.s. constant. (see also: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013864/equality-in-jensens-inequality-for-strictly-convex-functions), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160095/convexity-and-equality-in-jensen-inequality) for proof details).

Your Jensen is an equality and the function ($\ln$) isn't affine, so the random variable $q(X)/p(X)$ must be a.s. constant.  Since $q$ and $p$ are mass functions, the constant must be 1.